# WPF Grid, remove highlight of cell click

Tags: wpf, highlight, grid-layout

I have a window like this

```
<Window x:Class="Värvivärten_Sendscreen.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sendscreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="Sendscreen" Height="768" Width="1024" Background="white" ResizeMode="NoResize"  KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" FontFamily="Ubuntu" Foreground="#2B2525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="768" >
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0">
                <Image Source="/logo.png" Width="156"  Margin="-170,20,0,0"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="60,50,0,0" >
                    <Image Source="/estonia.png" Width="40" Height="40"></Image>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="300" FontSize="14" Padding="20,0,0,0">Smart text
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Label></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="60,20,0,0" >
                    <Image Source="/united-kingdom.png" Width="40" Height="40"></Image>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="300" FontSize="14" Padding="20,0,0,0">Smart text
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="60,20,0,0" >
                    <Image Source="/latvia.png" Width="40" Height="40"></Image>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="300" FontSize="14" Padding="20,0,0,0">Smart text
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="60,20,0,0" >
                    <Image Source="/russia.png" Width="40" Height="40"></Image>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="300" FontSize="14" Padding="20,0,0,0">Smart text
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,100">
                    <Image Source="/qr.png" Width="82"></Image>
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold">Smart text</Label>
                    <Label Margin="0,-10">Smart text</Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
        <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Label FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,50" >Smart text</Label>
            <ListView x:Name="TvBox"  BorderThickness="0" Background="white" VerticalAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="4">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="115*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="115*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" 
                    Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" 
                    Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageData}" Margin="0" Width="115" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Image x:Name="BigImage" Width="400" Margin="0,40,0,0"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

All of the small images that are bound are clickable by this. I would like to remove the background highlight and border from them when clicked. How can I do so?

Comment: if you don't plan to use ListView selection feature (SelectedItem), you can replace ListView with ItemsControl. Otherwise you should research and find one of duplicate questions regarding your issue

Comment: @ASh awesome, mind forming that into an answer?

Comment: @ASh this also removes any padding that previously existied and adding it manually makes the box flicker in position and size when I change ItemsSource in full from code behind...